# group policy service pack 3 BSOD

Tags: bsod, windows-xp

Has anyone had any problems pushing out sp3 though active directories group policy.
I have a had full of Dell Optiplex 740 PC running xp pro SP2 w/AMD Atholon 64 x2 4050e.
Every time i push out sp3 after reboot i get a BSOD "STOP: 0x0000007E (0xC0000005, 0xF79ED8EB, 0xF79ED7F4, 0xF79ED4F0)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common problem with Dell and HP computers with AMD processors. You need to change the registry setting of "Start" to value "4" in this key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\intelppm`

before upgrading to SP3
Since it's already failed, you'll need to uninstall the SP. [Directions here for that](http://aumha.net/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=33246).